# Number of invertible {0,1} real matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, enumerative-combinatorics

This question is inspired from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18547/number-of-unique-determinants-for-an-nxn-0-1-matrix), where it was asked what possible determinants an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in {0,1} can have over $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: how many such matrices have non-zero determinant?

If we instead view the matrix as over $\mathbb{F}_2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer is

$(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-2^2) \dots (2^n-2^{n-1}).$

This formula generalizes to all finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$, which leads us to the more general question of how many $n \times n$ matrices with entries in { $0, \dots, q-1$ } have non-zero determinant over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A046747

Comment: In particular, follow Zivkovic's link on the page for A046747.  He has the most recent data for small n that I have found.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.03.18

Comment: I have yet to find anyone addressing the spectrum question for (0,1,...,q-1) matrices or related questions.  I look forward to anyone posting a pointer to such material.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.03.18

Comment: What does the obvious chinese remaindering argument give you: in other words, the biggest the determinant could be is $n^n$ (by Hadamard). Now, assuming (that's the big problem obviously) that the probability that a $0, 1$ matrix mod $p$ is singular is the same as the probability that a random matrix is singular, then you get an obvious product over primes for the probability. Is this close to the conjectured answer?

Comment: The link Steve Huntsman gives has been moved to http://oeis.org/A046747

Comment: The asymptotics of this sequence were recently obtained by Tikhomirov. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09016.pdf  Someone should probably update the OEIS for A046747 and http://oeis.org/A057982

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [Sloane, A046747](http://oeis.org/A046747) for the number of singular (0,1)-matrices.  It doesn't seem like there's an exact formula, but it's conjectured that the probability that a random (0,1)-matrix is singular is asymptotic to $n^2/2^n$.

Over $F_2$ the probability that a random matrix is nonsingular, as $n \to \infty$, approaches the product $(1/2)(3/4)(7/8)\cdots = 0.2887880951$, and so the probability that a random large matrix is singular is only around 71 percent.  I should note that a matrix is singular over $F_2$ if its real determinant is even, so this tells us that determinants of 0-1 matrices are more likely to be even than odd.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Is there an elementary proof of why the determinant is more likely to be even than odd?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm hardly an expert on random matrices.

Comment: Fill in a size $n$ square matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$
row by row. If the first $n-1$ rows are linearly independent,
the whole matrix will have zero determinant. Otherwise
the last row will cause the determinant to vanish if its
entries satisfy a linear equation; this happens with
conditional probability $1/2$.

Comment: I think you mean "linearly dependent".

Answer (score 17):

As Michael noted, the conjectured bound for the probability a random $(0,1)$ matrix is singular is $(1+o(1)) n^2 2^{-n} $.  This corresponds to the natural lower bound coming from the observation that if a matrix has two equal rows or columns it is automatically singular.

The best bound for a long time for this problem was $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + o(1) )^n$, due to [Bourgain, Vu, and Wood](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0461).  Corollary 3.3 in their paper also gives a bound of $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}+o(1))^n$ in the case where entries are uniformly chosen from $\{0, 1, \dots, q-1\}$ (here the conjectured bound would be around $n^2 q^{-n})$

Even showing that the determinant is almost surely non-zero is not easy (this was first proven by Komlos in 1967, and the reference is given in Michael's Sloane link).

Update: Konstantin Tikhimorov has uploaded a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09016) giving a bound of $(\frac{1}{2}+o(1))^n$ on the singularity probability in the $(0,1)$ case, matching the lower bound up to the $o(1)$ in the exponent) (the result stated in his paper is for $\pm 1$ matrices, but there's a bijection showing that the singularity probability of an $n \times n$ $\pm 1$ matrix is the same as that of an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix with entries uniformly from $\{0,1\}$).

Answer (score 2):

Lurking around MO, I found a question which is related to the second part of my question.  Namely, Greg Martin and Erick B. Wong prove that assuming that the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix are chosen randomly with respect to a uniform distribution from the set $\{-k,  \dots, k\}$, then the probability that the resulting matrix will be singular is $\ll k^{-2 + \epsilon}$.

See this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90591/singular-matrices-with-integer-entries) (where the above paragraph is plagarized from) and also [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/AAIMHNIE.pdf) for the link to the Martin & Wong paper.