# Density of perfect matching count in $k$-partite graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, perfect-matchings

Let $f(G)$ give number of perfect matchings of a graph $G$.

Denote $\mathcal N_{n}=\{0,1,2,\dots,n!-1,n!\}$.

Denote collection of all $kn$ vertex balanced $k$-partite graph (each color is on $n$ vertices) to be $\mathcal G_{kn}$.

At every fixed $k\in\mathbb N$ there are many $m\in\mathcal N_{n}$ that do not have a $G\in \mathcal G_{kn}$ such that $f(G)=m$ (for $k=2$ refer [Are all numbers from $1$ to $n!$ the number of perfect matchings of some bipartite graph?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236713/number-of-perfect-matchings-of-bipartite-graphs)).

For a given $n$ and given $k$ denote by $\mathcal T_{k,n}$ to be the subset of $\mathcal N_{n}$ such that for every $m\in\mathcal T_{k,n}$ there is a $G\in\mathcal G_{kn}$ such that $f(G)=m$.

> 1. Is the asymptotic $\log_2|\mathcal T_{k,n}|=\frac{\log_2|\mathcal N_n|}{\Omega((\log_2n)^{\frac1{k-1}})}$ at every $k\in\{2,3,\dots,\}$ valid?

> 2. Is the asymptotic valid if $k=\Omega(\log_2\log_2n)$?